# PHP MySQL - Saber si entrada ya existe (o no)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo un página PHP para realizar registros (grabar, consultar y borrar), unos datos de entradas (solo números), que guardo en una base de datos, y tengo una inquietud con la función GUARDAR.

Quiero **detectar** si **el número a guardar ya existe** (O NO), en mi base de datos.

1 - Si existe, detener el evento de guardar y mostrar un `echo`.

2 - Si no existe, guardarlo (ya tiene confirmación por echo).

¿Cuál sería el código correcto que debo agregar a GUARDAR para verificar si el numero ya existe ó no...?

Gracias!

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Grabar Nuevo" name="btn_registrar">    
<input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="btn_consultar">
<input type="submit" value="Eliminar" name="btn_eliminar">
```

**PHP (para grabar nuevo):**

```
$numero ="";
$plaza ="";
$tarjeta ="";

if(isset($_POST['btn_registrar']))
  {
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $plaza = $_POST['plaza'];
  $tarjeta = $_POST['tarjeta'];

if($numero=="" || $plaza=="" || $tarjeta=="")
  {
  echo "No puedes guardar campos vacíos";
  }

else {
     $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (numero,plaza,tarjeta) values ('$numero','$plaza','$tarjeta')");
     echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
  }
}
```

**PHP (completo):**

```
<?php
include("abrir_conexion.php");

$numero ="";
$plaza ="";
$tarjeta ="";

// =============== REGISTRAR =============== -->

if(isset($_POST['btn_registrar']))
{
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $plaza = $_POST['plaza'];
  $tarjeta = $_POST['tarjeta'];

  if($numero=="" || $plaza=="" || $tarjeta=="")

  {
    echo "No puedes guardar campos vacíos";
  }

  else {
  $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (numero,plaza,tarjeta) values ('$numero','$plaza','$tarjeta')");

  echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
  }
}

// =============== CONSULTAR =============== -->

if(isset($_POST['btn_consultar']))
{
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $existe=0;

  if($numero=="")
  {
    echo "El Número no puede estar vacío";
  }

  else {
  $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE numero = $numero");
  while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))

  {
  echo
    "
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Número</center></td>
     <td><center>Plaza</center></td>
     <td><center>Tarjeta</center></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><b><center>".$consulta['numero']."</center></b></td>
     <td><b><center>".$consulta['plaza']."</center></b></td>
     <td><b><center>".$consulta['tarjeta']."</center></b></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<br>
      ";

  $existe++;

    }
 if($existe==0)
    {
 echo "NO EXISTE";
    }
  }
}

// =============== ELIMINAR =============== -->

if(isset($_POST['btn_eliminar']))     
{
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $existe=0;

  if($numero=="")
  {
    echo "El Número no puede estar vacío";
  }

  else {
  $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE numero = $numero");
  while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))

  {
    $existe++;
  }

  if($existe==0)
  {
    echo "El Número que quieres borrar no existe";
  }

  else {
  $_DELETE_SQL = "DELETE FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE numero = '$numero'";
  mysqli_query($conexion,$_DELETE_SQL);

  echo "Número de Envío borrado correctamente";

    }
  }
}

include("cerrar_conexion.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo  utilizando la sentencia de sql: `EXISTS` para verificar si existe dicho dato en la base de datos.

```
$resultado=$conexion->query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE numero='$numero');");
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

    if ($row[0]=="1") {                 

            //Aqui colocas el código que tu deseas realizar cuando el dato existe en la base de datos
    }else{
           //Aqui colocas el código que tu deseas realizar cuando el dato NO existe en la base de datos
    }
```

Comment: Hola. No funciona. Los datos se confirman como guardados, pero no se guarda nada en la base de datos.

Comment: Espero que ahora esta mas claro edite mi solución

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora si. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Lo principal seria, separar cada opcion para un mejor manejo en el backend, luego realizar la correspondiente verificacion, y manejar la respuesta con mayor facilidad en el frontend

```html
$exists = number_exists($your_number, $bd);
if( $exists > 0 ) {
  $information["respuesta"] = "EXISTE";
  echo json_encode($information);
}
else {
  save_new_number($your_number, $bd);
} 

function number_exists($your_number, $bd) {
  $stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT number FROM tbl_name WHERE number = :your_number;");
  $stmt->execute(array(':your_number'=>$your_number));
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  return $count;
}

function save_new_number ($your_number, $bd) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$your_number');";
  $result = $bd->prepare($query);
  $result->execute();
  checking($result);
}

function checking( $result ) {
  if( !$result ) $information["respuesta"] = "ERROR";
  else $information["respuesta"] = "BIEN";
  echo json_encode( $information );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. De momento se me va un poco de mis alcances (novato en php nivel 0), y prometo estudiar tu aporte. Saludos.

Comment: Deberías estudiarlo atentamente, primero porque es más elegante y segundo porque soluciona un problema de SQL Injection que las demás soluciones, no, incluído la mia.

Comment: Tambien seria recomendado, considerar el uso de PDO. Da le con todo, todos empezamos de algun modo.

Answer (score 1):

Hola en **grabar nuevo** en la parte de **else**, podrías verificar de esta manera.

```
$check = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE numero='$numero'");
$count = $check->columnCount();
if($count>0){
   echo "Ya existe el numero";
}else{
  $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (numero,plaza,tarjeta) values 
   ('$numero','$plaza','$tarjeta')");
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Clinton , pero algo estoy haciendo mal (seguro), porque no me guarda los números nuevos, y tampoco me avisa si ya existe, además de que perdí los echo (ya no se muestran). Los cambios de **guardar** los he publicado en jsfiddle. Si lo puedes revisar estaré más que agradecido: https://jsfiddle.net/csqhxrt5/

Comment: Hola intenta cambiar el metodo columnCount por rowCount()

Comment: También funcionaría SELECT count(numero) AS registros ... y luego if($check->registros >0).

Comment: Lo he solucionado con el aporte de @Santiago aunque el tuyo es igualmente válido. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar UNIQUE de mysql para prevenir los registros repetidos, en tu caso la solución es hacer:

```
ALTER TABLE $tabla_db
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_unique_name UNIQUE KEY(numero, plaza, tarjeta);
```

Ahora, en caso de hacer el insert de un elemento repetido, recibirás el error desde mysql:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'xxxxxx' for key 'constraint_unique_name'
```

Por lo que solo tienes que comprobar en tu código si el insert devuelve error o no:

```
if (!$conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (numero,plaza,tarjeta) values ('$numero','$plaza','$tarjeta')")) {
    echo "Registro duplicado.";
} esle {
    echo "Registro insertado.";
}
```

Aquí te dejo la ayuda para entender mejor el manejo de errores de mysql desde PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Y aquí para entender el uso de UNIQUE:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Logicamente también puedes hacer como ya te han sugerido, un select previo para ver si ya existe o no el registro.

Answer (score 0):

```
//$conn debe estar previamente definido para ingresar a la base de datos, p.ej. $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;",$username)

$records=$conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email');
$records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$records->execute();
$results=$records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($results) && count($results)>0){
    $message='email ya existe';
} else {
//proceder a hacer el registro
}
```