# Saber si ya existe un dato en mi Tabla de PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, tablas

Quiero saber si $usuario ya existe dentro de mi tabla, si existe que muestre el error de que existe ese usuario y que ingrese otro.
Si me podrían ayudar se los agradecería un montón

```
    <?php  
    include('bd.php');
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","pma","","rol");
    $validar=0;
    
    #FORMULARIO REGISTER
    if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        //Llamo a los input por metodo _POST
        $usuario=$_POST['user']; 
        $contraseña=$_POST['password'];
        $nombre=ucfirst($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellido=ucfirst($_POST['apellido']);
        
        $sql="INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `user`, `contraseña`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `IDcargo`)
 VALUES (NULL, '$usuario', '$contraseña', '$nombre', '$apellido', '2')";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            if($resultado){
            
                header("location: index.php");
                echo "Datos ingresados a la BD";
                $validar=1;
                
            }else {
                $error= "Los datos no se ingresaron correctamente";
                
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Lo correcto es que `usuarios.user` sea `UNIQUE`. Y así cuando intentes insertar el mismo usuario podrás cachar el error, ya sea con [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) o con [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tengo un ejemplo de validación:

```
$resultado=$conexion->query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $yourtable);");
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

if ($row[0]=="1") {                 
        //Si existe...
}else{
       //Si no existe...
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No me sirvió, lo toma como que no existe

Comment: puede que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317161/php-mysql-saber-si-entrada-ya-existe-o-no) te ayude